# Developing A Loop To Solve Powers In Kotlin Android

Tags: loops, kotlin

**I have been given an assignment which I have been stuck on for the last few weeks as I have no clue on where to proceed on how to do it.
The Question is as Follows:
The app must be able to calculate powers. For example, if the user enters 2 and 3,
the calculation should be 23. Do this calculation by using a loop, to calculate 2 x 2 x 2.
Use the notation 2^3 = 8 for the display>
Here Is the code that I managed to do for the rest of the app **

````
package com.example.poepart1_1

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.lang.Math.sqrt


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var num1: EditText     // User Entered Variable 1
    private lateinit var num2: EditText     // User Entered Variable 2
    private lateinit var add: Button        // The addition Button
    private lateinit var minus: Button      // The Subtraction Button
    private lateinit var multiply: Button   // The Multiplication Button
    private lateinit var division: Button     // The division Button
    private lateinit var sqroot: Button
    private lateinit var power: Button
    private lateinit var output: TextView    // The Text View Output that displays the answer to the given sum.


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Linking all attributes and finding their ID's that I have assigned them to in the .xml file

        num1 = findViewById(R.id.num1)
        num2 = findViewById(R.id.num2)
        add = findViewById(R.id.add)
        minus = findViewById(R.id.minus)
        multiply = findViewById(R.id.multiply)
        division = findViewById(R.id.division)
        sqroot = findViewById(R.id.sqroot)
        power = findViewById(R.id.power)
        output = findViewById(R.id.output)


        power.setOnClickListener {
                if (num1.text.toString() == "0") {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You Cannot Use 0 As A Power. Please Enter A Different Value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }else{
                val num = num1.text.toString().toInt()
                val num2 = num2.text.toString().toInt()
                val result = "$num ^ $num2 ="

                output.text = "$result"

            }
        }

    }
}```
````

Comment: The assignment tells you to use a loop - if you don't know anything about loops, learning about those would be a good place to start! If you do know how to use them, then think what a loop is - a repeating set of instructions. How could you use that to multiply a number by itself *n* times? If it helps, any number to the power *0* is *1* - that might be a good starting point

Comment: (And if this _weren't_ an assignment, then it would probably be a great example of an [X-Y problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): if you just want to calculate powers, you shouldn't start off assuming that a loop is the right structure to use.)